# Passing a string using argparse

Tags: python

I've been reading through the documentation and the tutorial, but there is one thing I don't quite understand.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("test string", type=str, help="this is a string")
args = parser.parse_args()
print args
```

When I run `$python prog.py 'test'` the result is:

`Namespace(test string='test')`

How do I get it to print just `test`?

Comment: What do you mean *"just `test`"*? As opposed to what, exactly?

Comment: It's considered a namespace object instead of a string

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're after. You have a namespace with a single attribute whose name is "test string" (should probably stick to valid identifiers there...) and whose value is "test". That's exactly what you asked for. What precisely were you expecting?

Comment: Ahh, so I want to pass that string into another function. As a sample use case, concatenate a string but I get the error `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Namespace' objects`

Comment: So pass `args.get('test string')` (again, this would be easier if you used a valid identifier).

Comment: what do you mean valid identifier?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers. In general, I suggest you have a look at Python's documentation rather than guessing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("teststring", type=str, help="this is a string")
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.teststring
```

Answer (score 1):

It's highly unusual to use a name with a space in it, since it makes it difficult to get values back out.

The documentation has this to say about the object that is returned from `parse_args`:

> This class is deliberately simple, just an object subclass with a readable string representation. If you prefer to have dict-like view of the attributes, you can use the standard Python idiom, vars()

So, to treat args like a dictionary you can do something like this:

```
print var(args)["test string"]
```

You can also do it this way:

```
print getattr(args, "test string")
```

Note that if your option does not have spaces in it (eg: "teststring") you can access the attribute directly:

```
print args.teststring
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand everything that is going on with your code, but having a space in the name of your argument seems to be a bad idea. If I use the following code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("test_string", type=str, help="this is a string")
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.test_string
```

then

```
python temp3.py test
```

gives me what you want.

when you create the "test string" name for the argument it is not clear (at least to me) how you can access its value using the 'dot' notation.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for!